# Getting quarter corresponding to date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I have to get dates in my date column in 4 quarters Q1,Q1,Q3,Q4 using mysql query.

These are basically quarter.

for example year  month is:

```
2012       May -march -  2012Q1
2012       April-June  - 2012Q2
2011       July- SEP   - 2011Q3
2010       OCT - Dec   - 2010Q4
```

I am doing it with different if else conditions and getting confused. It there any simple way to do this ? Or it will be better to make a stored procedure for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you want to get [quarter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter) from given date. It's simple to get and no need for stored procedure.

You can use mysql function `QUARTER()`  to get quater of given date.

like :

```
select concat(left(datefield,4),QUARTER(datefield) ) as mydate from tablename
```

Comment: Using `YEAR(datefield)` instead of `LEFT(datefield,4)` would be more consistent with `QUARTER(datefield)`, in my opinion, but either should work well, I guess.